# document on appear not working

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, animate.css

Im loading content though ajax, all works.

But iv got the appear.js file and the animate.css file

The following 2 wont work and i dont know why. Does anyone know why this is not working?

```
$(document).on('appear', '.animated', function(){

    var dis = $(this);
    var animation = dis.data('animation');
    var delay = dis.data('delay');

    if(delay){
        setTimeout(function(){
            dis.addClass(animation);
        }, delay);
    } else {
        dis.addClass(animation);
    }
});
```

and this

```
$('.animated').appear(function(){
    var dis = $(this);
    var animation = dis.data('animation');
    var delay = dis.data('delay');

    if(delay){
        setTimeout(function(){
            dis.addClass(animation);
        }, delay);
    } else {
        dis.addClass(animation);
    }
});
```

Comment: need more information!!! How does it break?  Do you get an exception?  What is the exception?

Comment: erm  , i tryed with adding click instead on appear and did an alert and that worked. Its just not working with the appear. Are you allowed to call a plugin like this? Or should the appear be where the on is?

Comment: Event delegation only works if the event bubbles. The `appear` event probably doesn't bubble to the document (since the document is always visible).

Comment: Thanks, so how do i fix this?

Comment: "appear" isn't an event, therefore it can't be done this way. You can't use event delegation unless you have an event. We need to know what adds the `.animated` element to help you solve this.

Comment: `Im loading content though ajax,` So in success callback of ajax, once new elements added, call appear() method on them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `appear` event won't be triggered on an element until after you've initialized the plugin with `$(element).appear()`. Since you're loading elements dynamically with AJAX, you need to initialize the plugin on the new elements. So your callback needs to be something like:

```
.done(function(response) {
    $("#someDiv").html(response);
    $("#someDiv").find(".animated").appear().on("appear", function() {
        ...
    });
});
```